# Linear operator $T$ is diagonalizable iff $V=N(T-\lambda I)\oplus R(T-\lambda I)$ for every $\lambda \in \mathbb C$.

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

Suppose that $V$ is a finite dimensional complex vector space and let $T\in L(V)$ be an operator on $V$. Then $T$ is diagonalizable iff $V=N(T-\lambda I)\oplus R(T-\lambda I)$ for every $\lambda \in \mathbb C$.

Here $N=:$null and $R=:$ range.
I tried to prove the above statement as follows but got stuck midway:

Suppose that dim V$=:n\gt 0$. $V$ has a basis consisting only of eigenvectors of $T$ say $v_i's, 1\le i\le n$. Let $\lambda_j$'s, where $1\le j\le m$ be the distinct eigenvalues of $T$. Clearly, the following inequality holds $1\le m\le n$.

If $\lambda\ne \lambda_j$ for any $1\le j\le m $, then $T-\lambda I$ is one -one and hence invertible (by rank-nullity theorem).

*For any $x\in V$, there exists a unique $u_x\in V$ such that $\left(T-\lambda I\right)u_x=x$.

So $(T-\lambda I)(x-(T-\lambda I)u_x)=(T-\lambda I)(x-x)=0\implies x-(T-\lambda I)x\in N(T-\lambda I)\implies x\in N(T-\lambda I)+(T-\lambda I)x\in N(T-\lambda I)+R(T-\lambda I)$. It follows that $V=N(T-\lambda I)+R(T-\lambda I)$.

If $y\in N(T-\lambda I)\cap R(T-\lambda I)$, then there is some $w$ such that $$(T-\lambda I)w=y\implies (T-\lambda I)^2w=0\implies (T-\lambda I)w=0\implies y=0$$

So $V=N(T-\lambda I)\oplus R(T-\lambda I)$ for every $\lambda\in \mathbb C\setminus \{\lambda_j: 1\le j\le m\}$.

I don't understand how to prove the above statement for $\lambda_j$'s. The problem is that in such case $T-\lambda_j I$ is not 1-1 so the statement * above won't hold anymore.

Any hints on how to proceed further?

Comment: Do you know that $T$ is diagonalizable implies $V = N(T) \oplus R(T)$?

Comment: @DionelJaime: I’m afraid I don’t.

Comment: @DionelJaime: I know that now. I understand that that solves my problem. Thank you!